# Jackson deserialisation mappings to Java Generics

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson

What I am trying to do is the following: Given a JSON document, map it to a POJO using Jackson, but define the type of the Generic class member based on a field in the JSON document.

My JSON looks as follows

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "parameters": [
                    {"name": "paramName","value": "Value1", "@type": "string"},
                    {"name": "size","value": 5,"@type": "double"}

                 ]
}
```

The class that maps to this JSON doc is

```
public class Strategy {
    public String name;
    public List<Parameter<?>> parameters;
}
```

Then I have a Generic class for this as follows

```
public class Parameter<T> {
    public String name;
    public T value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

So the idea is to tell Jackson when you deserialize the JSON document into the Strategy class and get to the parameters field, use the following classes as the Generic data type for the value member, i.e. I want to select it to be String or Double or Integer but I want that to be my decision so that it's generic and can be extended to any data type I want.

I realise I can use the annotation JsonTypeInfo which I added as well like this

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@type")
```

But using these classes as is actually works but Jackson decides itself what the type should be based on its value and my size parameter is set to an Integer. If I set its value to 5.0 then its set to a Double which works, but what if I want one of the parameters to be a custom object?

The only way I could get this to work (and am not 100% happy with the solution) is to make the Parameter class abstract and then create concrete classes for each type that I want, i.e. ParameterString, ParameterDouble, ParameterCustomClass and then use the @JsonSubTypes annotations to set the correct class to use based on the type field in the JSON document.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=ParameterString.class, name="string"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=ParameterDouble.class, name="double"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=ParameterInstrument.class, name="instrument")
})
```

With the following class as an example

```
public class StrategyParameterString extends StrategyParameter<String> { 

}
```

This isn't very extendable, I guess it will just need a new subtype annotation and concrete class added for every type that I need, but just doesn't feel as elegant as it could be.

Does anyone know of a better way of handling this ?

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: I'm just curious why you want to do this.  Java implements generic types by erasure.  This means that the generic type parameter exists and has meaning only at compile time.  They do not exist at run time.  The runtime `class` object for your `List<Parameter<?>>` is `List.class`.  If you need to associate type information with a non-reifiable type, I suggest that you create a type-safe heterogenous container and store that in your List, e.g. `List<MyHeterogenousContainer>`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @scottb. Basically I got to this point by initially creating a class for every type I needed, having them implement an interface and having my List<ParameterInterface>, there were two problems there, firstly when I iterated over the list the object didnt know anything about the class members unless I cast it and secondly each class had duplicate code, so I refactored it into a base abstract class to reduce the code duplication. I guess the concrete class implementations sets the type at compile time so that may be a better way of handling it then due to Java erasure.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the types you want to represent in your `Parameter` list are reifiable, eg. String, Double, Instrument.  You can take advantage of the fact that reifiable types have a runtime type token in the form of their class literal.  This can be exploited to form the basis of a heterogenous type safe collection.

Instead of defining your Parameter class this way:

```
public class Parameter<T> {
    public String name;
    public T value;
    :
    :
    }
}
```

You can define it as a concrete class that associates the object's value with its run time type token.

```
public class Parameter() {
    private final Object    m_value;
    private final Class<?>  m_cls;

    private Parameter(Class<?> token, Object val) {
        m_value = val;
        m_cls = token;
    }

    public static <T> Parameter newInstance(Class<T> token, T value) {
        return new Parameter(token, value);
    }
    :
    :

    public <T> T getValue(Class<T> token) {
        if (token != m_cls) throw new ClassCastException("Type error");
        return token.cast(m_value);
    }
}
```

In this setting, type tokens and generic methods (rather than a generic type) are used to set and reestablish the type linkage for the desired value.  The value you set can be any type and is guaranteed to be returned as the same type that you stored as long as the type tokens are consistent.

Note that constructors can not be generic.  To address this, the constructor for Parameter has been made private and Parameter instances are formed by invoking the `newInstance()` static factory method (which can be generic).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation @scottb, much appreciated. Just so I understand this Parameter class that you have written above, the 2 fields it has are the value (m_value) and the class that the value represents (m_cls) which is why the getValue method casts the value to the correct class type? I wonder if this is going to work with Jackson de-serialization?

Comment: `Class` is serializable (and Class<?> is reifiable).  If the other reference types in your project are serializable as well, I don't see why this can't be made to work.  The comparison in the `getValue()` method may need to be omitted.  The problem is that the check on the host platform asserts that the type of the object value is the same as that which is being requested.  May not work on the client.  If the check is omitted, then the cast is unchecked; there's no guarantee that you'd be requesting the same type as that which was stored.